# Create new txt file inside directory PYTHON SCRIPT

Tags: python, linux, loops, directory, txt

I wanted to create a new txt file inside each directory each loop.

```
import os 

path='/home/linux/Desktop'
os.chdir(path)

for i in range(10):
    NewDir = 'File' + str(i)
    os.makedirs(NewDir)
```

how can I put txt file in each created directory? thankyou

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your code is creating 10 new *folders* called File0, File1, etc.

Comment: Look at the function `open()`. You will need mode `"w"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file creation is handled at opening. In your for loop, just add this:

```
open(NewDir + "/your_file_name.txt", 'w').close()
```

EDIT: added "/" to file name

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. it did create the txt file but it's not inside the newly created directory. how can I make it inside the directory instead? thank you

Comment: Seems weird ? Did you write `NewDir + "your_file_name.txt"` or `"your_file_name.txt"` only ?

Comment: exact same as ```file = open(NewDir + "your_file_name.txt", 'w').close()```

Comment: Oh ok, maybe you should add a "/" : `"/your_file_name.txt"` then ? You can look for os.path.join() too, to avoid this kind of mistake

Comment: You welcome. For you to know: The / indicates that what is before is a folder => I think it created 10 files "FileXyour_file_name.txt" ? Then, the / means that "FileX" is the folder in which you want to create the file. (`os.path.join(NewDir, "your_file_name.txt")` should work too, to create the path to the new file ;) )

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to create a new file is the following:

```py
open(filepath, 'a').close()
```

The append (`'a'`) mode will note overwrite existing files and create a new empty file if none exist. If you want to overwrite existing files, you can use the `'w'` mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to simplify file/directory manipulations.

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/home/linux/Desktop')
for i in range(10):
    new_dir = path / f'File{i}'
    new_dir.mkdir()
    (new_dir / 'some.txt').write_text('Some desired content')
```

Comment: If the base path is not guaranteed to exist, you may want to use `new_dir.mkdir(parents=True)`.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it shows invalid syntax on ```new_dir = path / f'File{i}'```

Comment: It means that you're on Python < 3.6. Then you can replace it with `new_dir = path / 'File{}'.format(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `os.mkdir` it is going to create a `new folder` named as `File0`...,`File9`. You can try this to create file:

```
import os

path='/home/linux/Desktop'
os.chdir(path)

for i in range(10):
    open(f"File{i}.txt","w").close()
```

This is going to create files under `/home/linux/Desktop` named as `File0`,`File1`,.....,`File9`.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm creating 10 new folders. But I wanted to create 1 txt file inside of each created folders. How can I do that? thank you